# RichTextField uneditable with Draftail in Wagtail 2.0

Tags: python, wagtail

I updated my website (development version) to wagtail 2.0 and all RichTextField attributes of my pages are totally uneditable, with Draftail.js. I added the following lines, in my settings.py:

```
WAGTAILADMIN_RICH_TEXT_EDITORS = {
    'default': {
        'WIDGET': 'wagtail.admin.rich_text.HalloRichTextArea'
    }
}
```

to revert back to the former Hallo.js editor, and it works correctly. But when I remove it, the content that is already saved is not printed and there is no editing feature anymore. Here is the model definition:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel

class BlogIndexPage(Page):
    intro = RichTextField(blank=True,features=[
        'h2',
        'h3',
        'ol',
        'ul',
        'bold',
        'italic',
        'link'
    ])

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('intro', classname="full")
]
```

And my settings.py file:

```
import os
from decouple import config

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',

    'wagtail.contrib.forms',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects',
    'wagtail.embeds',
    'wagtail.sites',
    'wagtail.users',
    'wagtail.snippets',
    'wagtail.documents',
    'wagtail.images',
    'wagtail.search',
    'wagtail.admin',
    'wagtail.core',

    'modelcluster',
    'taggit',

    'homepage',
    'blog',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'wagtail.core.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.contrib.redirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'lsvwebsite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'site.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': config('NAME_DB'),
        'USER': config('USER_DB'),
        'PASSWORD': config('PASSWORD_DB'),
        'HOST': config('HOST_DB'),
        'PORT': '',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-  validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

#media files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

#wagtail site name
WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = 'Site Name'

WAGTAILADMIN_RICH_TEXT_EDITORS = {
    'default': {
        'WIDGET': 'wagtail.admin.rich_text.HalloRichTextArea'
    }
}
```

It looks like an issue, with the new Draftail.js editor…

Edit 1: errors printed in web console, with Firefox Quantum 58.0.2

```
TypeError: o.a.createElement is not a function    draftail.js:1:241051
TypeError: window.draftail is undefined    edit:560:1
```

Edit 2: errors printed in web console, with Opera 51.0

```
draftail.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: o.a.createElement is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (draftail.js:1)
    at t (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (draftail.js:1)
    at t (vendor.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (draftail.js:1)
    at t (vendor.js:1)
    at window.webpackJsonp (vendor.js:1)
    at draftail.js:1
(index):560 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initEditor' of  undefined
    at (index):560
rangy-core.js:80 [Deprecation] The behavior that Selection.addRange() merges existing Range and the specified Range was removed. See  https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6680566019653632 for more details.
(anonymous) @ rangy-core.js:80
```

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the javascript console of your browser?

Comment: @gasman indeed, I didn’t think about checking it, I edited the post with the errors. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, no obvious clues from that error message... - what browser / version are you using?

Comment: @gasman I’m using Firefox Quantum 58.0.2

Comment: @gasman I tested with Opera 51.0, I have the same result in the browser, but the errors printed in console are different, I added them in the post

Comment: Have you tried to clear browser's cache?

Comment: This looks a lot like a browser/proxy cache issue - from the logs, Draftail fails to initialise because the `vendor.js` file that your browser loads is the previous version’s. See also https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/3700.

Comment: I ran into the same errors with my browser's cache. Are you storing static files on AWS S3 by any chance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first I tried I clearing the cache, it didn't work. 
Then I remembered I’m used to set firefox to clear the cache automatically, when it closes, so I checked my firefox settings and it was indeed set like so. Then, I tried @fixgoats solution, I cleared the static files I did not created myself and run collectstatic, it did not work. And I remembered I should not have to run collectstatic in the dev environment, so I deleted them without running collectstatic again, it did not work, so I cleared the cache (since I did not close firefox during the process) and it there worked.

My guess is, I had the outdated static files stored directly in dev static directory and firefox was using and caching those outdated files (one problem hiding the other). Now, it all works fine, really big thank to all of you.

Comment: yay! Glad to hear you solved it. You should pcik your own answer as the solution so other people find it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had the same issue, at least the titles of the error messages are the same and the description is quite similar. What worked for me was deleting the static wagtailadmin javascript directory and running collectstatic again. Though I still have no idea what actually caused the bug.